# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: typescript, webpack, импорт, export

Почему происходит данная ошибка и как её исправить?

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test' in '/Users/maks/Documents/MyProgramms/TestProject/src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 3:13-30
```

Файловая структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

index.ts

```
import { User } from './test';
let user = new User('ivan');
```

test.ts

```
export class User {
    name: string;

    constructor(name:string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.37",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.ts'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    },
    target: 'node'
};
```

Так же пробовал импортировать через require, использовать awesome-typescript-loader и обновить webpack до последней версии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте свойство:

```
// webpack.config.js

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
}
```